# call a function in themes in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

I have a file in my yii first project. my project has a new theme with this path

```
first_proj\themes\project\views\layouts\main.php
```

and i want to call a function in it like below

```
<?php
    if($is_project_manager){
?>
        <div class="each-pop-el" style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="showAllMemberTask()">show tasks</div>
  <?php } ?>
```

and have function in 
first_proj\protected\controllers\project.php
this is

```
public function actionIsProjectmanager(){
        $project_manager = false;
            $crt = new CDbCriteria;
            $crt->condition = 'user_id=:uid and role=1';
            $crt->params = array('uid'=>Yii::app()->user->id);
            $project_manager= projectMember::model()->findAll($crt);
            // $model_result = MyModel::model()->test();

            $this->render('the url to theme and main.php file', array('is_project_manager' => $project_manager));
    }
```

how can i reach to that main.php file ? what i must write instead of
`the url to theme and main.php file` in my function ?

Answer (score 0):

You set the controllers `layout` to the file. So it would look like this:

`$this->layout = 'main';`

Layouts must be rendered with a view file as well though.

```
$this->render('index', array('is_project_manager' => $project_manager));
```

Then place an `index.php` file in your `views/project` folder with the actions content.

This assumes you've setup your config to have the theme as `project`

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to know is: **No need to pass layout file to the view.** When you use `render()` function, yii automatically add layout to your view. Then, For specifying the layout, you need to use `$this->layout = '//layouts/main` in your action.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your view

```
<?php
    if($this->isProjectmanager){
?>
        <div class="each-pop-el" style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="showAllMemberTask()">show tasks</div>
  <?php } ?>
```

and create a helper function (not an action!) in your controller

```
public function IsProjectmanager(){
    if ($someConditon) {
       return true;
    }
    else  {
       return false;
    }

    }
```